# UNIX/LINUX localhost server in a windows machine

Tags: linux, unix, xampp, lamp

I'm using XAMPP for windows to build my website projects, but I need to create a website in a UNIX/LINUX based server, but since I'm using XAMPP it is a Windows based server.
Somebody knows how can I do that in a windows machine, without having to install Linux in my machine?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Install VirtualBox and run a VM of your favorite linux distribution. My suggestion would be Debian or Ubuntu.